# XMLHttpRequest to external form with textarea and checkbox

Tags: javascript, checkbox, xmlhttprequest, textarea

I am trying to send an XMLHttpRequest to an external form which contains a textarea and a checkbox. I would like to substitute the text inside the textarea (“Put your text in this box”) for another string and to uncheck the checkbox, then sending the form and getting the results.
The form is more or less like this:

```
<form name="aspnetForm" method="post" action="Tagger.aspx" id="aspnetForm" enctype="multipart/form-data">

      <input id="checkBoxOptions_0" type="checkbox" name="checkBoxOptions$0" checked="checked" />

      <textarea name="$txtbxInput" id="_txtbxInput">Put your text in this box.</textarea>

      <textarea name="$txtbxOutput" readonly="readonly" id="_txtbxOutput" class="output">Output box</textarea>

      <input type="submit" name="$btnTagIt" value="Tag It" id="_btnTagIt" class="sizeTopMargin" />
</form>
```

And I have tried the XMLHttpRequest with two different options: the first one gets back the textarea with the original string and the checkbox checked as default, the second one gives the error explained in one of its lines.

Option 1:

```
var data = "checkBoxOptions$0.checked=false"+"&$txtbxInput=New String Inserted";
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('POST', "http://nlpdotnet.com/services/Tagger.aspx", true);
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "multipart/form-data");
xhr.onload = function () {
    var results = xhr.response;
}
xhr.send(data);
```

Option 2:

```
var formElement = document.getElementById("aspnetForm");
var formData = new FormData(formElement);//TypeError: Argument 1 of FormData.constructor is not an object
formData.append("$txtbxInput", "New String Inserted");

var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('POST', "http://nlpdotnet.com/services/Tagger.aspx", true);
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "multipart/form-data");
xhr.onload = function () {
    var results = xhr.response;
}
xhr.send(formData);
```

As the form is external, I cannot redesign any part of it. Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Your `data` string is not in the correct format for `multipart/form-data`. You should probably use `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` format if you're going to construct the data string by hand.

Comment: This is the format specified in the original form, nothing changes if I change it.

Comment: Well, your data isn't in URL-encoded form, either. URL encoding looks like `param1=value1&param2=value2`. You don't have `&` between them.

Comment: And for checkboxes you don't send a `.checked` parameter. You just send `checkboxname=value` if it's checked, and leave it out if it's not checked.

Comment: Yes, it is URL-encoded (typo error, now corrected), I do have & between parameters.

Comment: About the checkbox, it is checked by default. I have also tried checkBoxOptions$0=false, without the .checked, and nothing changes

Comment: Sending =false doesn't make it unchecked. Clients only send checked checkboxes to the server. To make it not checked, you don't send it at all.

Comment: `$0` is an ASP.net thing, right? I don't know anything about ASP, so I'm assuming you're doing that part right.

Comment: I think it's just a name, I have made XMLHttpRequests to forms with different technologies and it has never been a problem.

Comment: Checkbox: if I don't send it, it remains checked

Comment: I'm not talking about whether it's checked in the browser, we're just changing what gets sent to the server in the AJAX request.

Comment: I mean the form has `name="checkBoxOptions_0"`, but you have `checkBoxOptions$0` in the Javascript. I assume that's some kind of ASP.net placeholder that gets replaced with `_0`, `_1`, etc. as part of a loop.

Comment: It is checked by default, and I cannot change this value wheter I send it or not.

Comment: You are mixing id and name. Name is checkBoxOptions$0.

Comment: Sorry about that. Anyway, when you do `formData.delete("checkBoxOptions$0");` it will send that the checkbox isn't checked, even though the checkbox is actually checked on the web page.

Comment: That's fine, but I cannot reach the checkbox if I get this error retrieving the form, so...

Comment: If you put your code at the end of the HTML or run it in `window.onload`, you won't get an error retrieving the form.

Comment: I cannot modify the HTML, as it is in an external resource.

Comment: Don't modify the HTML, run your script in `window.onload` or `document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded")`

Comment: How are you adding the Javascript to the document without modifying it somehow?

Comment: I don't load any window. I am developing a Web Extension (former Chrome Extension) that sends an XMLHttpRequest when the user selects a word.

Comment: Then I can't understand why it can't find the element. By the time the user is able to select words, all the HTML should be loaded, so the form element should exist.

Comment: The form is in the page that the user is selecting a word from, right?

Comment: I am then sending a form filled by the extension, an XMLHttpRequest to the "action" field of the form with fields filled by it.

Comment: No, the user selects a word in one document and I send the XMLHttpRequest to a different resource.

Comment: It does find the form. What does not work is the line 'var formElement = document.getElementById("aspnetForm");' before the XMLHttpRequest.

Comment: That's the form it doesn't find. See my updated answer.

Comment: What you proposed is more or less what I was doing in the first option. I have tried though, but still not working, it does not change the innerHTML of textarea.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be trying to get the form element with `getElementById`. The form isn't in the DOM of the current page, it's in a completely different document that isn't loaded into the browser.

You just need to construct the `formData` by hand with a bunch of `add` calls:

```
var formData = new FormData;
formData.add("$txtbxInput", "New String Inserted");
formData.add("$btnTagIt", "Tag It");
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('POST', "http://nlpdotnet.com/services/Tagger.aspx", true);
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "multipart/form-data");
xhr.onload = function () {
    var results = xhr.response;
}
xhr.send(formData);
```

Comment: Thanks, but the line "var formData = new FormData(formElement);" throws the error: "TypeError: Argument 1 of FormData.constructor is not an object", so the following lines are not executed.

Comment: What does `console.log(formElement);` show? Are you running this code in an event listener after the DOM is loaded? Are you sure you have the correct ID in the line `var formElement = document.getElementById("aspnetForm");`?

Comment: console.log(formElement) shows null. I have double-check the form id, it is correct. No, I don't use an event listener. This is the first interaction I have with the website and that's why, in my opinion, formElement is null, cause the DOM hasn't still charged when I declare it. All the examples I've seen have the DOM and the javascript code in the same document.

Comment: Where are you running this code? It needs to be after the HTML, or you need to run it in `window.onload`. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14028959/why-does-jquery-or-a-dom-method-such-as-getelementbyid-not-find-the-element

Comment: Why are you submitting a form before the user has had a chance to type into it?

Comment: The HTML is in an external website. I am developing a js file for accessing this website's form